# Python - Display All Node Attributes Networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

How do I display node attributes (particularly the name of the node).
Here's what I have so far:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_node('home')
g.node['home']['value'] = 10
```

I would like to something like

```
if node_name == 'home' and node[node_name]['value'] == 'somewhere':
    DoSomethingCool()
```

Also, is there a way to get access to the node data when using functions like 'get_predecessors' or 'get_successors'?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Nodes attributes are stored in `dict`. You can easily access them with standard dictionaries manipulations:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_node('home')
g.node['home']['value'] = 10

for k,v in g.nodes(data=True):
    print(k,v['value'])
```

Output:

```
('home', 10)
```

I cannot answer the second part of your question (get_predecessors or get_successors) because these functions are not part of the networkx library.